# How to perform effective painting in python?

Tags: python, optimization, graphics, pyqt5, rendering

I want to do a project that displays a planet with continents and climatic zones.

I am currently using PyQt5 for painting, with QPainterPath:

[image: gif with results]

There are two problems:

1. With this approach, it's hard to define zones inside the continent.
2. Painting is quite slow (calculations are fast, thanks to numpy).

Minimal code for Path creating way:

```
import sys
import time

import numpy as np
import math
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QSlider
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QPainterPath, QPen
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

class TwoDMap(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, size):
        super().__init__()
        self.size = size
        self.W = self.size.width() # width of screen
        self.H = self.size.height() # height of screen
        self.qp = QPainter()

        self.circleRadius = self.H/3 
        self.pointsAcc = 30 # defines how many points will be between main points

        self.interface_start_point = [50, 50]
        self.circle_start_x = self.interface_start_point[0] + 100
        self.circle_start_y = self.interface_start_point[1] + 200

        # vars for converting points from math syster to screen system
        self.scrcoord     = np.array([self.circle_start_x + self.circleRadius , 
                                self.circle_start_y + self.circleRadius, 0])
        self.scrcoordcoef = np.array([1, -1, 1])

        
        ######### Vars for rotatiob ###############

        # angles
        self.rotation_x = 0
        self.rotation_y = 0
        self.rotation_z = 0

        self.axis_x = np.array([1, 0, 0])
        self.axis_y = np.array([0, 1, 0])
        self.axis_z = np.array([0, 0, 1])

        ############################################

        # main point of star
        points = np.array([
            [self.circleRadius, math.pi/10  ,  -math.pi/10,  ], 
            [self.circleRadius, math.pi/4.5 ,  math.pi/5.5,  ],
            [self.circleRadius, math.pi/3   ,  0      ,      ],
            [self.circleRadius, math.pi/3   ,  math.pi/5,    ],
            [self.circleRadius, math.pi/2   ,  math.pi/4,    ],
            [self.circleRadius, math.pi/2.75,  math.pi/3,    ],
            [self.circleRadius, math.pi/2.75,  math.pi/2,    ],
            [self.circleRadius, math.pi/4   ,  4*math.pi/10, ],
            [self.circleRadius, math.pi/5.5 ,  5.5*math.pi/8,],
            [self.circleRadius, math.pi/6   ,  math.pi/3,    ],
        ])
        # convert to decart coordinates
        self.points = np.apply_along_axis(self.sphericToDecart, 1, points)
        
        self.initUI()

        self.showFullScreen()
    
    def initUI(self):

        self.setWindowTitle('2DMap')
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: black; color: white; font-size: 20px;")

        # sliders for rotating
        self.angleScale = 100
        self.polz1 = QSlider(Qt.Horizontal, self)
        self.polz1.setGeometry(self.interface_start_point[0] + 10, self.interface_start_point[1] + 10, 200, 30)
        self.polz1.setRange(int(- 2 * math.pi * self.angleScale), int(2 * math.pi * self.angleScale))
        self.polz1.setValue(0)
        self.polz1.valueChanged.connect(self.angleChanged)

        self.polz2 = QSlider(Qt.Horizontal, self)
        self.polz2.setGeometry(self.interface_start_point[0] + 10, self.interface_start_point[1] + 40, 200, 30)
        self.polz2.setRange(int(- 2 * math.pi * self.angleScale), int(2 * math.pi * self.angleScale))
        self.polz2.setValue(0)
        self.polz2.valueChanged.connect(self.angleChanged)

        self.polz3 = QSlider(Qt.Horizontal, self)
        self.polz3.setGeometry(self.interface_start_point[0] + 10, self.interface_start_point[1] + 70, 200, 30)
        self.polz3.setRange(int(- 2 * math.pi * self.angleScale), int(2 * math.pi * self.angleScale))
        self.polz3.setValue(0)
        self.polz3.valueChanged.connect(self.angleChanged)

    def angleChanged(self):
        # func for rotating picture with slider 
        self.rotation_x = self.polz1.value()/(2*self.angleScale)
        self.rotation_y = self.polz2.value()/(2*self.angleScale)
        self.rotation_z = self.polz3.value()/(2*self.angleScale)
        self.update()

    def paintEvent(self, e):  
        self.qp.begin(self)
        self.qp.setRenderHints(QPainter.Antialiasing) 

        self.qp.drawEllipse(int(self.circle_start_x), int(self.circle_start_y), int(self.circleRadius*2), int(self.circleRadius*2))
        self.qp.setPen(QPen(Qt.green, 3, Qt.SolidLine))


        path_obj = self.getSpherePath(self.getPointsToDraw())
        self.qp.drawPath(path_obj)
        
        self.qp.end()
    
    def getPointsToDraw(self):
        points: np.ndarray = self.allPointsRotationOffset(self.points)

        # preparations for computing points
        nw = points
        nw2 = np.zeros(points.shape)
        nw2[-1:] = points[0]
        nw2[:-1] = points[1::1]
        crs2 = np.cross(np.cross(nw, nw2), nw)
        crs2 = (crs2.T / np.sqrt(np.sum(crs2 * crs2, axis=1)) * self.circleRadius).T
        alphas = np.arcsin(np.sqrt(np.sum((nw2 - nw) * (nw2 - nw), axis=1)) / (2 * self.circleRadius)) * 2

        # determine the number of points depending on the angle between them
        endp = ((self.pointsAcc+1) * (alphas / (np.pi / 2)))
        endp: np.ndarray = endp.astype(np.int16)
        pnts = [0] * points.shape[0]
        
        for i in range(points.shape[0]):
            
            rngs = range(endp[i]+1) * alphas[i] / endp[i]
            rng_cos = np.cos(rngs)
            rng_sin = np.sin(rngs)

            pnts[i] = self.getInterPoints(nw[i], crs2[i], rng_cos, rng_sin)
       
        return pnts
    
    def getSpherePath(self, allpoints):
        # func for creating actual path, that will be drawn on screen
        path = QPainterPath()
        first_point = True
        line_break = False
        for points in allpoints: # for all point group
            for point in points: # for all points in group

                # drawing only points with z > 0
                if (point[2] > 0):
                    if first_point:
                        # for first point we need to move to it
                        path.moveTo(point[0], point[1])
                        first_point = False
                    if line_break:
                        # now we have point with z > 0, but before this we had point with z < 0
                        # that means we need to move to new part
                        path.moveTo(point[0], point[1])
                        line_break = False
                        continue
                    
                    # connect points (z > 0) with simple line
                    path.lineTo(point[0], point[1])
                    
                else:
                    # we need to disconect line, because point have z < 0 and must not be shown
                    line_break = True
        return path

    
    def getInterPoints(self, basis_i, basis_j, rng_cos, rng_sin):
        # function computes points between two main points 
        # and covert them to screen coord. system with center on sphere center
        arr =  np.outer(basis_i, rng_cos) + np.outer(basis_j, rng_sin)
        return arr.T * self.scrcoordcoef + self.scrcoord
    
    def allPointsRotationOffset(self, points: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
        # Rotate points along axises with angles: rotation_z, rotation_y, rotation_x
        rotated_pointsZ = self.kvantRotation(points,          self.axis_z,  self.rotation_z)
        rotated_pointsY = self.kvantRotation(rotated_pointsZ, self.axis_y,  self.rotation_y)
        rotated_pointsX = self.kvantRotation(rotated_pointsY, self.axis_x,  self.rotation_x)
        return rotated_pointsX

    def kvantRotation(self, p: np.ndarray, u, f):
        sin  = np.sin(f/2)
        Sa   = np.cos(f/2)
        q    = sin * u 
        qp0  = np.matmul(p, -1 * q)
        ABC  = np.cross(q, p) + Sa * p 
        qqp  = np.outer(qp0, q) 
        prm  = -1 * np.cross(ABC, q) - qqp
        trr  = Sa * ABC
        ans2 = prm + trr 
        return ans2
    
    def sphericToDecart(self, point):
        # Convert points from spheric system to decart system
        xyz = np.array([
            math.sin(point[1]) * math.cos(point[2]), 
            math.sin(point[1]) * math.sin(point[2]), 
            math.cos(point[1])
        ]) * point[0]
        return xyz

def start():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = TwoDMap(app.primaryScreen().size())
    app.exec_()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    start()
```

So I tried another method: using triangles for painting continents:

[image]

But this approach is MUCH slower than I thought it would be and slower than the previous method.

Code for triangles:

```py
class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.W = 800
        self.H = 800
        self.CoF = 50 
        self.dx = 0
        self.initUI()
    

    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(50, 50, self.W, self.H)
        self.setWindowTitle('Zamo')
        self.poligons = []
        self.poligons_points = []
        self.triangleZam()
        self.show()

    @profile
    def paintEvent(self, e):
        
        start = time.time()
        qp = QPainter()
        qp.begin(self)
        qp.setRenderHints(QPainter.Antialiasing)

        
        pointsF = [
            QPoint(430 - 300 + 200, 370 - 300 + 200),
            QPoint(440 - 300 + 200, 500 - 300 + 200),
            QPoint(260 - 300 + 200, 550 - 300 + 200),
            QPoint(420 - 300 + 200, 600 - 300 + 200),
            QPoint(420 - 300 + 200, 800 - 300 + 200),
            QPoint(530 - 300 + 200, 640 - 300 + 200),
            QPoint(680 - 300 + 200, 740 - 300 + 200),
            QPoint(630 - 300 + 200, 560 - 300 + 200),
            QPoint(720 - 300 + 200, 430 - 300 + 200),
            QPoint(570 - 300 + 200, 450 - 300 + 200),
        ]
        main_poli = QPolygon(pointsF)
        main_rect: QRect = main_poli.boundingRect()
        qp.setBrush(Qt.lightGray)
        qp.setPen(QPen(QColor(0, 0, 0, 255), 1, Qt.SolidLine)) # Qt.lightGray QColor(0, 0, 0, 0)

        # self.poligons - list of QPoligon's
        # self.poligons_points - list of point of poligons (used for optimization)
        # main_poli - star 
        # main_rect - QRect, bounding the star
        for i in range(len(self.poligons)):
            qp.setBrush(Qt.lightGray)
            if main_rect.contains(self.poligons_points[i][0]): # if triangle inside the Rect, then check for intersecting
                if main_poli.intersects(self.poligons[i]):
                    qp.setBrush(Qt.green) 
            qp.drawPolygon(self.poligons[i])

        qp.setBrush(QColor(0, 0, 0, 0))
        qp.setPen(QPen(QColor(255, 0, 0, 150), 1, Qt.SolidLine))
        qp.drawPolygon(main_poli)
        qp.end()
        print(time.time() - start)

    def triangleZam(self):
        r = int(self.W/self.CoF)
        midDot =  r / np.sqrt(3)
        a, b = 0 - r, 0
        c, d = r/2 - r, midDot
        e, f = r - r, 0
        
        for j in range(int(self.H/midDot + 1)):
            a = 0 - r / (j % 2 + 1)
            c =     r / 2 - r / (j % 2 + 1)
            e = r - r / (j % 2 + 1)
            for i in range(int(self.CoF + 1)):
                points = QPolygon([QPoint(a, b),QPoint(c, d),QPoint(e, f)])
                #qp.setBrush(Qt.darkGray)
                points2 = QPolygon([QPoint(c, d),QPoint(e, f),QPoint(c+r, d)])
                self.poligons.append(points)
                self.poligons.append(points2)
                self.poligons_points.append([QPoint(a, b),QPoint(c, d),QPoint(e, f)])
                self.poligons_points.append([QPoint(c, d),QPoint(e, f),QPoint(c+r, d)])
                a = a + r
                c = c + r
                e = e + r
            b = b + midDot
            d = d + midDot
            f = f + midDot
```

So, my question is: is there some way to achieve faster painting in python (algorithms, libraries)? Or maybe is there some resource I can study about 2D rendering basics?

Comment: How are you producing those polygons?

Comment: @musicamante, generating them before app started. Or maybe you want to see actual code for poligon points?

Comment: I see that you're using a projection, so I assume that the actual painted triangles are computed at each variation of the rotation angle. So, yes, how are those points computed? Or how are the QPainterPath created?

Comment: @musicamante, edited code for triangles.

Comment: what about the QPainterPath approach?

Comment: @musicamante, could be better, i'll try it, but no so much

Comment: I didn't ask you how good is it, I asked you how the QPainterPaths are generated. What you need to know is very specific, as such implementations and optimizations can differ a lot depending on each situation, so we also need to know how your code works *specifically*.

Comment: @musicamante, you are right, i added code for QPainterPath approach.

Comment: Can you provide a [mre] for the QPainterPath too, as you did for the triangle example? I believe there could be a partial solution, but having a complete and reproducible example would help to ensure that. Including basic rotation and animation would help a lot. Please take your time to craft such an example, don't rush it: a better example will make our "job" easier to find possible solutions and possibly provide more complete answers.

Comment: @musicamante, got it, i'll do that

Comment: @musicamante, take a look